# In minecraft bedrock there are no mobs anywhere. Even animals and villagers are not there

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I set the mode to normal and then changed to easy. I also enabled keep inventory cheat and turned off the others.I can't figure out the problem. Please help me.

Comment: We'll need more details to deduce your problem. Are you sure? Maybe you just got unlucky, have you seen no mobs for abnormally long? If not, could you give a screenshot of your settings?

Comment: Yes, no mobs from when I used the world.
I think the mob loot and mob griefing settings I turned off in activate cheats plays a role in this problem, but I can't tell it for sure.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I changed it to easy when I saw a skeleton and its spawner. So I changed normal to easy. The bonus chest and starter map are always enabled in most worlds. So I think they're not the problem.

Comment: Sorry I figured it out, it is mob spawning, the cheat I turned off. So there were no mobs. now I have all the mobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if you didn't disable gamerule doMobSpawning.

Comment: Or the "disable raids" options. However he said that not even villagers appear which is concerning

Comment: Yeah in cheat I disabled mob spawning so I wasn't able to see any mobs. Thank you 

Comment: @JRBros If an answer answers your question, click the tick mark below the score number.

Comment: Sorry I don't know. Thanks for informing me!